# Implementing views in node webkit desktop application

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, node-webkit

I am creating a file copier desktop application using node webkit. My application will have a flow. When it is opened, it will check whether any profile date exists or not and accordingly it will open the first page. I will have a header which will never change and it has links/buttons to different views. 
My question is how do I implement views in node webkit and use some nice transitions on change of the view. Here is a rough idea of what I want to implement.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Node webkit is a runtime that allows you to execute node.js apps on native platforms. Views and transitions would be done that same way as you would on the web ... via html templates and css.

Comment: I ended up using bootstrap tabs.